# ajax - Google cached version not showing text

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a web site which loads content via ms ajax from an asp.net webservice. When I look at the cached version in Google, I don't see the initially loaded text.

My question is what would be the best way to gracefully degrade for no JS clients like Googlebot, for this type of architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put it there as plain HTML, everytime. If you're reloading it after, it will be only avaible for javascript-allowed browsers

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could server side pick up the user agent string and return plain HTML content.